# Активный пункт меню в joomla

Tags: css3, joomla

Всем привет, подскажите, как сделать активный пункт меню в joomla.

Я уже пробовал

```
.menu li:active
.item-108 current active
.item-108:active
```

ничего из этого мне не помогло, что делать?

Comment: Если у продукта есть официальный сайт, то лично я стараюсь черпать информацияю из первоисточника. А так как по Joomla есть не только русскоязычный сайт, но и [форум](http://joomlaforum.ru/), то почему бы не задать этот вопрос там?

Answer (score 1):

В joomla у `li` есть класс `.active`, используйте его.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось вместо `:active` надо было писать `.active`

```
.menu li.active
```